# Does 'each other' function as singular or plural?

Tags: grammatical-number, verb-agreement

Are either of the following sentences grammatically correct?

> We know what each other are doing

and

> We know what each other is doing

Neither of them sounds right to me, but surely one of them must be, depending on whether 'each other' functions as a singular or plural? Of course there are workarounds like *"Each of us knows what the other is doing"*, but is it possible to keep the words "each other" together in such a sentence?

Comment: I agree that neither sounds right—which is exactly why neither is grammatical. _Each other_ cannot function as the subject of a finite verb in my idiolect of English; I would have no other option than to rephrase to “We each know what the other is doing”. Note that this is also much closer to [how the phrase _each other_ originated](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=each+other) to begin with (and how it’s still used in some other languages, like French).

Comment: _Each_ and _other_ are both determined NPs, and they're singular. What you mean to say is _Each of us knows what the other is doing_. Putting them together  is not necessary, though it is common. BTW, the term for _each other_ is Reciprocal Pronoun; it's a sort of a generalization of Reflexive Pronoun, and it shows up with them sometimes (like _Each man considers the other to be superior to himself_).

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/608536/2085).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you notice that *each other,* while idiomatic, is not unbreakable, it begins to come clear.

The reciprocal phrase *each other* can be separated into one determiner binding something in the subject (*each, each one*), and one determiner binding something in the object (*other, the other*), viz:

- *Each (one) of us knows what the other (one (of us)) is doing.* (dual)
- *Each (one) of us knows what the others/other ones are doing.* (plural)

And some of these quantifiers may be floated to pre-verbal position:

- *We each know what the other (one) is doing.* (dual)
- *We each know what the others/other ones are doing.* (plural)

From this it's easy to see how *each* and *other* hook up:

- ***Each*** of us knows the **other**.
- *We **each** know the **other**.*
- *We know **each other**.*

But that doesn't resolve the number problem that comes from having two determiners potentially conflicting. So both

- **We know what each other is doing.* 
  and
- **We know what each other are doing.*

feel wrong.

Of course, there are other quantifiers that specify more precisely,
especially when they're separated, viz:

- *We both know what the other is doing.* (dual)
- *We all know what the others are doing.* (plural)

Comment: Why doesn't the same problem arise with *we know each other's schedule(s)* then (or does it?)

Comment: @Minty I suspect _each other_ has been univerbated enough to be allowed to function as possessor, but the reciprocality of it makes it semantically impossible as subject. This is the same in other Germanic languages that have univerbated reciprocals: Da. _hinanden_, Sw. _varann/varandra_, etc., are happy to be possessors, but cannot be subjects. In fact, I don’t know of any language where a reciprocal can act as subject.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Yes, but why, if the basic problem is that the compound is trying to be singular and plural at the same time? Anyway, I'm not sure *each other* is trying to function as subject. I realise it's in subject position, but I think the *each* is still trying to reach back to the matrix subject. Its function is to specify that the members of a subject group are to be regarded as having distinct relationships with the verb, I think, which is why we can say *we each ate our ice-cream* even though more than one ice-cream got eaten.

Comment: I think the problem with OP's sentences is that the *each* cannot get past the *what* so as to hook up with the matrix subject. The same would happen with *that* in *we know that each other is reliable*. I'm interested in the number conflict idea but at the moment it seems to me that the numbers don't conflict because one applies to the subject and one to the object.

Comment: The point of saying that each member of the subject group has a distinct relationship with the verb is normally to highlight that they don't also have the same relationship (it is a several relationship only, not a joint and several relationship). That's why, in the Q that seems to have prompted this new answer about singular and plural, *each hiker climbed a hill* implies that the hikers were not together, meaning that there's no reason to assume it was the same hill (as in the Q in the survey).

Comment: @Minty I don’t really think the compound _is_ trying to be singular and plural at the same time. Since it cannot be subject, there is no way to tell whether it is singular or plural to me – it is simply anumeric, so the crux of this question is a non-issue to me. I don’t think _each_ can be trying to reach back to the matrix subject here, because that would leave _other_ on its own, which would require a determiner to be a valid subject in the embedded clause (“We each know what _the_ other is doing”).

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet But that's what the answer we're commenting on says, isn't it? That there is a number problem that "comes from having two determiners potentially conflicting" and that "the reciprocal phrase each other can be separated into one determiner binding something in the subject (each, each one), and one determiner binding something in the object (other, the other)".

Comment: @Minty More or less, yes. I was speaking more in terms of syntax, whereas John is talking more about semantics: _each_ does of course relate semantically to the subject, and _other_ to the object; but syntactically, _each other_ is just one pronoun, one that cannot function as subject (to me). It can of course be broken up (as John does), but that creates a syntactically very different construction.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet If you say for the sake of argument that the *each* bit does relate syntactically to the subject, it follows that it has been moved in a construction like *they really like each other*. It also follows that *the* can only be dropped when *each* is moved next to *other*. As I understand it, *what X is doing* is an NP complement in the sentences above, and therefore an island. If so, you'd expect it to block the movement and prevent the use of *each other*, and the dropping of *the*. This is just what seems to happen, so I still don't think the *each* is trying to act as subj.

Comment: @Minty: No, those don't follow at all from _each_ relating to the subject. Each conclusion above is a separate hypothesis that must be presupposed before going further, and for which evidence is necessary. Separable _each_ and _other_ does not negate the fact that _each other_ is a fixed form in Modern English, with its own unique set of affordances and limitations, some of which are related to those of _each_ and _(an)other_. It's just not that simple.

Answer (score 2):

"Each other" refers to a singular subject, just like "one another" does. Notice "each" and "one" are singular; so are "other" (an other v. others) and "another" (which is like a contraction or compression of "an other").

Another way to think of it is: "we know what each other is doing" means "I know what he is doing and he knows what I am doing"...all singular.

Comment: Great, thanks. Does this mean "we know what each other is doing" is grammatically correct?

Comment: We know what the other is doing would be correct.

Comment: It may be grammatical to you, but it certainly is not to me, regardless of verb agreement. The first sentence in this answer is untrue in my English, because _each other_ (and _one another_ and all other possible reciprocals) does not refer to any kind of subject at all. Reciprocals simply cannot function as subjects. Sentences like these are embedded questions, but unembedding the question here yields, “What is/are each other doing?” – which I hope you agree is quite impossible.

Answer (score 1):

No, neither needs to be correct because there is a problem of verb agreement.  "We" means you and I (inclusively, anyway), so instead of "is doing", you'd need "are doing" for "you" and "am doing" for "I".  There is no such problem with "They know what each other is doing" (which, however, still seems a bit odd).

Comment: "We know" is the independent clause. There is no problem of verb agreement. There would be a problem if it were written "we knows."

Comment: The sentence might be improved by writing: "we know what the other is doing"; nevertheless, "each other" is singular.

Comment: @Justine, Whether there is a problem of verb agreement depends on the order of application of the verb agreement rule and the rule that introduces "each other".  So you don't know that there is no problem.

Comment: However I rephrase the sentence, each other takes "is"; "we" does not.

Comment: @Justine, If you begin with "I know what you are doing, and you know what I am doing", there is no apparent way to get to a version with "is doing".  But if you begin with "He knows what she is doing, and she knows what he is doing" you can get to "... each other is doing" without the difficulty of rationalizing "are" and "am" somehow to get "is".  That's the difference.

Answer (score 0):

I would typically phrase something like this as, "We each know what the other is doing." Otherwise, your verb-subject agreement is off. "Is" is singular and we is plural. By adding "each," it becomes the subject associated with the verb. Like, "We each took a cookie from the jar."

Apologies for my typo...  I had "know" rather than "is." My fault.

Comment: Actually, "know" is plural (they know) and "knows" is singular (he knows).

Comment: Thank you for pointing out my typo. My fingers took off without my brain.

Answer (score -2):

It is not grammatically correct to use it like "each other have gotten _____" because this usually functions as a plural, as in "we would help **each other** out".

Comment: Hi Yeeter, welcome to EL&U. Note that this site is a bit different from other Q&A sites: unlike on a discussion forum, an answer here is expected to be *authoritative, detailed, and explain why it is correct* - preferably citing a published reference (hyperlinked to the source) as evidence to support your answer. You can [edit] your post to add this detail; for further guidance, see [answer] and take the EL&U **[Tour]** :-)